# Trying to connect remote (linux) server from vscode in windows 11 but showing xhr failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, connection, ubuntu-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhvl1.png)

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem downloading configuration file from az764295.vo.msecnd.net . For that you can download it externally and copy paste it to your linux server. Also, vs code automatically download this file while trying to connect with ssh, for that request your network administrator to open 443 port to open az764295.vo.msecnd.net on your linux server. To know whether the port is open or not ping  az764295.vo.msecnd.net and telnet  az764295.vo.msecnd.net 443. It is one time fixation.

Answer (score 1):

try copying vs code configuration files  to you server or you can download from https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz